# Receiving parameter null in the controller when passing values from a form in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form in the Home index page that ask the user which patient wants to see, and ask for the SSN (Social Security Number) number that is a foreign key in the table DIAGNOSIS. When the user enter the SSN (Social Security Number) and pass the data to the controller the app stops and says parameter cannot be null.

```
<form asp-controller="Diagnosis" asp-action="Index"  method="post">
        Social Security Number: 
    <input asp-for="Patient.Email" type="email" style="width:50%;" placeholder="Social Security" >
    <button type="submit" class="button" style="padding:10px;">
        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>Search
    </button>

    Name: 
    <input asp-for="Patient.Name" type="text" style="width:40%;" placeholder="Patient Name">
    <button type="submit" class="button" style="padding:10px;">
        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>Search
    </button>
</form>
```

The controller

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    int _id = int.Parse(id);

    List<Diagnosis> diagQuery = context.Diagnosis
                                       .Where(d => d.SocialSecurityPatId == _id)
                                       .ToList();

    return View(diagQuery);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code of the controller?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You’re calling a post endpoint but based on the lack of attribute on the method as well as the content of method looks more to me like a get?